# List of user images feched from API in React are displayed and all 10 images flash to each user image then the 10th user image stays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, image, state

I am developing a Top10UserList Component in React that fetches the top 10 users from the api, then fetches the image for each of those users and creates an image tag for each user sucessfully, and is supposed to display each user's image in their own tag.

Unfortunately though, every one of the images shares the same state, so they all flash quickly through all 10 images and then stay on the final image.

I need them to be seperate and but I am not sure how I can refactor my code to achieve this.

React Component:

```
const TOP_USERS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/users/top-players'
const TOP_TEN_USERS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/users/top-10-players'
const TOP_TEN_USERS_IMAGES_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/image-files/download-using-username'
const USER_IMG_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/image-files/'
class TopUserList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { users: [], top10Users: [], token: '', top10UsersImages: [], profUrl: '', profileImage: '' };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(TOP_USERS_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ users: data }));

        fetch(TOP_TEN_USERS_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ top10Users: data });

                console.log(data);
                console.log("Data[0]")
                console.log(data[0].username)

                data.forEach(element => {

                        const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + element.username;
                        const id = element.id;

                        fetch(imgUrl, {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
                            }
                        })
                            .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
                            .then(buffer => {
                                const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
                                this.state.img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            });

                        const fetchImage = async (url) => {
                            try {
                                const response = await fetch(url, {
                                    headers: {
                                        "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
                                    }
                                });
                                const imageBytes = await response.arrayBuffer();
                                var blob = new Blob([imageBytes], { type: "image/jpeg" });
                                var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                return imageUrl;
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log("ERROR:", error);
                            }
                        };

                        const profileUrl = "profile-image-" + id;

                        this.state.profUrl = profileUrl;

                        (async () => {
                            const imageSrc = await fetchImage(imgUrl);
                            console.log("ImageSRC:");
                            console.log(imageSrc);
                            console.log("Profile Url:");
                            console.log(profileUrl);
                            this.setState({ profileImage: imageSrc })
                        })();
                        console.log("Profile Url:");
                        console.log(profileUrl);

                        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<image id={profileUrl}>

`;
                    }
                );
            });
    }



    render() {
        const { users, top10Users, isLoading, profileUrl, profileImage} = this.state;
        console.log("Top 10 users data: ")
        console.log(top10Users);
        console.log("Top 10 users using index: ");
        console.log(top10Users[0]);
        console.log("ProfUrl: ");
        console.log(profileUrl);
        console.log("profImg");
        console.log(profileImage);

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        const topUserList = users.map(user => {
            return <tr key={user.id}>
                <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }} class="player-list-key-text">{user.name}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.username}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.location}</td>
            </tr>
        });

        const topTenUserList = top10Users.map(user => {
            return <div className="user-container" key={user.id}>
                <Card>
                    <div id="app"></div>
                    <img src={profileImage} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
                    <CardTitle>{user.name}</CardTitle>
                </Card>
            </div>
        })

        return (
            <div className="outer-div-container">
                <div>
                    <Container fluid>
                        <h3 className="player-list-header">Top Players</h3>

                        <Table className="mt-4">
                            <thead>
                            <tr id="player-list-row">
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Name</th>
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Username</th>
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Location</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {topUserList}
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>

                        {topTenUserList}
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TopUserList;
```

And the result:

[image]

How can I do this in React? Do I need to create 10 different image state values?

Thanks for any help!

Updated code:

```
class TopUserList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { users: [], top10Users: [], token: '', top10UsersImages: [], profUrl: '', profileImage: {} };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(TOP_USERS_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ users: data }));

        fetch(TOP_TEN_USERS_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ top10Users: data });

                console.log(data);
                console.log("Data[0]")
                console.log(data[0].username)

                const profileImagesData = {}

                data.forEach((element, userIndex) => {

                        const imgUrl = USER_IMG_URL + element.username;
                        const id = userIndex;

                        fetch(imgUrl, {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
                            }
                        })
                            .then(r => r.arrayBuffer())
                            .then(buffer => {
                                const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
                                this.state.img = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            });

                        const fetchImage = async (url) => {
                            try {
                                const response = await fetch(url, {
                                    headers: {
                                        "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
                                    }
                                });
                                const imageBytes = await response.arrayBuffer();
                                var blob = new Blob([imageBytes], { type: "image/jpeg" });
                                var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                profileImageData[element?.id] = imageSrc
                                return imageUrl;
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log("ERROR:", error);
                            }
                        };

                        const profileUrl = "profile-image-" + id;

                        this.state.profUrl = profileUrl;

                        (async () => {
                            const imageSrc = await fetchImage(imgUrl);
                            console.log("ImageSRC:");
                            console.log(imageSrc);
                            console.log("Profile Url:");
                            console.log(profileUrl);

                            this.setState({profileImage:{...profileImageData}})
                            
                            })();
                        console.log("Profile Url:");
                        console.log(profileUrl);

                        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<image id={profileUrl}>

`;
                    }
                );
            });
    }



    render() {
        const { users, top10Users, isLoading, profileUrl, profileImage} = this.state;
        console.log("Top 10 users data: ")
        console.log(top10Users);
        console.log("Top 10 users using index: ");
        console.log(top10Users[0]);
        console.log("ProfUrl: ");
        console.log(profileUrl);
        console.log("profImg");
        console.log(profileImage);

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        const topUserList = users.map(user => {
            return <tr key={user.id}>
                <td style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }} class="player-list-key-text">{user.name}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.username}</td>
                <td class="player-list-key-text">{user.location}</td>
            </tr>
        });

        const topTenUserList = top10Users.map(user => {
            return <div className="user-container" key={user.id}>
                <Card>
                    <div id="app"></div>
                    <img src={this.state.profileImage[user.id]} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
                    <CardTitle>{user.name}</CardTitle>
                </Card>
            </div>
        })

        return (
            <div className="outer-div-container">
                <div>
                    <Container fluid>
                        <h3 className="player-list-header">Top Players</h3>

                        <Table className="mt-4">
                            <thead>
                            <tr id="player-list-row">
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Name</th>
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Username</th>
                                <th className="player-list-data-text">Location</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {topUserList}
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>

                        {topTenUserList}
                    </Container>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default TopUserList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by converting your profileImage state from a string value to an object where key of this object will be your user id and the value would be image url

In your code, you may need to make following changes

1. Your state variable `profileImage:''` inside constructor should
   be replaced by  `profileImage:{}`
2. In `componentDidMount`  Initialise a variable `const profileImageData = {}` above this line `data.forEach(element`
3. Under  `const imageSrc = await fetchImage(imgUrl);`, once you have the response, do
   `profileImageData[element?.id] = imageSrc` (I am assuming that you have an id variable on each of your
   top10User array)
4. Replace `this.setState({ profileImage: imageSrc })` with
   `this.setState({profileImage:{...profileImageData})`
5. Inside your top10UserList, replace  `<img src={profileImage} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />` with  `<img src={this.state.profileImage[user.id]} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />`

   If you do not have an id value then you can replace
   `data.forEach(element` with `data.forEach((element, userIndex)` and use `userIndex` as your key value instead of
   `element.id` and do the same in top10UserList as well

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, that makes sense but when I am trying to implement the changes the profileImagesData constant is never used, and many of the fields have unresolved variable types. Something must be in the wrong place, I have updated the question with the updatedcode with your steps. Thanks

Comment: Line 73:33:  'profileImageData' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 73:65:  'imageSrc' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 91:61:  'profileImageData

Comment: See if you are using the same variable name
I believe the const declaration is profileImagesData while the variable being used is profileImageData

Comment: Ah yes that was it, but imageSrc is also undefined? thanks

Comment: Updated step 3 for you. Remove profileImageData[user.id] = imageSrc from fetchImage function and follow step 3

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for your help, it is working perfectly!

Comment: Sounds Good to hear this